# local notification generating multiple notifications at the same time

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone, uilocalnotification

Sometimes local notification is generating multiple notifications for a single event number is 10. However I'm not getting in testing it's a rare case.

Is there any issue with a particular OS version ??
code is here

```
-(void)startLocalNotification:(NSDate *)notificationDate startTimeOfShift:(NSString *)startTime {

    NSLog(@"startLocalNotification");
    NSDateFormatter *newDateFormatter =[[NSDateFormatter alloc]init];
    [newDateFormatter setDateFormat:@"dd/MM/yyyy"];
    NSString *startDateStr =[newDateFormatter stringFromDate:notificationDate];
    NSString *scheduleDateTimeString =[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@ %@:00.000",startDateStr,startTime];
    NSLog(@"scheduleDateTimeString :%@",scheduleDateTimeString);

    NSDate *setFireDate,*notificationScheduledDateAndTime,*currentDate;

    [newDateFormatter setDateFormat:@"dd/MM/yyyy HH:mm:ss.SSS"];
    notificationScheduledDateAndTime =[newDateFormatter dateFromString:scheduleDateTimeString];
    setFireDate =[notificationScheduledDateAndTime dateByAddingTimeInterval:-60*15];
    currentDate =[NSDate date];

//    NSTimeInterval distanceBetweenDates = [notificationScheduledDateAndTime timeIntervalSinceDate:[NSDate date]];
//    NSLog(@"distanceBetweenDates :%f",distanceBetweenDates);

    NSLog(@"Current Date :%@ setFireDate :%@",currentDate,setFireDate);


    if(counts > 15){

        doNotShowNotificationAlert = NO;
    }

    switch ([currentDate compare:setFireDate]){

        case NSOrderedAscending: {

            NSLog(@"NSOrderedAscending");
        }
        case NSOrderedSame: {

            NSLog(@"NSOrderedSame");

            if(doNotShowNotificationAlert == NO){

                notification = [[UILocalNotification alloc] init];
                notification.fireDate = setFireDate;
            NSLog(@"setFireDate :%@",setFireDate);
                notification.alertBody = @"Shift Start Alert!! 15 mins to go.";
                notification.timeZone = [NSTimeZone defaultTimeZone];
                notification.soundName = UILocalNotificationDefaultSoundName;
                NSDictionary *infoDict = [NSDictionary dictionaryWithObject:@"100" forKey:@"notificationID"];
                notification.userInfo = infoDict;
                [[UIApplication sharedApplication] scheduleLocalNotification:notification];
                NSLog(@"info Dict :%@",infoDict);

                doNotShowNotificationAlert = YES;
            }
            break;
        }
        case NSOrderedDescending: {

            NSLog(@"NSOrderedDescending");
            break;
        }
    }

}
```

Comment: It is not an OS version issue.  Just make sure you function `startLocalNotification` is not being called multiple times in some condition.

Comment: actually the thing is that app is working properly from 2 years suddenly this issue came and only to 1 user, and i have checked startLocalNotification is called only once, that's why i am thinking is it any os version issue.